# Symbol not found: _XRContextFromDetailNode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to decode IOS trace file with a tool I got (no source code), and I got this. I supposed there was something to do with Xcode, so I reinstalled it, but it didnt help.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _XRContextFromDetailNode
  Referenced from: /Users/zhengyusen/Desktop/Workspace/streamtest/TraceDecoder
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsKit.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsKit

dyld: Symbol not found: _XRContextFromDetailNode
  Referenced from: /Users/zhengyusen/Desktop/Workspace/streamtest/TraceDecoder
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsKit.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsKit
```

Comment: Could you at least provide the name of the tool or the IOS trace file? It would be impossible to recreate your error otherwise

Comment: sry, that's the one: https://github.com/Qusic/TraceUtility

Comment: I tried to downgrade Xcode to 10.1 (as it seemed to work in others' Mac with Xcode 10.1), but when I ran the `instruments` command, it gave me this:               
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'